# toc- sections and subsections printing out of order

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I have a large presentation for a series of lectures - I have split it up into separate lecture files which I have then included in the main document e.g.

```
\section{ Algebra  }

\include{Lect1_Binomial_Expansion}

\include{Lect2_Quadratic_Factorisation}

\include{Lect3_Polynomial_Division}

\include{Lect4_Indices}

\include{Lect5_Logarithms}

\section{Functions}

\include{Lect6_Function_Notation}
```

I am not looking to include any numbering etc but what I find is that the subsections in Lect1 appear in the toc before the actual subheading (there are three subsections in the first lecture).  This happens later on too.  Any ideas why they are out of order?  Sorry I am very new to `beamer` - this is only my first week using it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: On `beamer` you have to insert the sections outside the `frame`. Are you doing this? Also, did you run `pdflatex` twice?

Comment: Yes thank karlkoeller I will look at the starter guide.  And Sigur yes I did put the section and subsection commands outside the frames.  And I have run the pdflatex at least five times.  Sorry if I didn't abide by the right format.

Comment: Don't use `\include`.